# Explicit user-defined conversion operator for lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

[The article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) devoted to lambda functions and particularly touches upon their `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()`. In the article the operator refered to as "a generic captureless lambda user-defined conversion function template."

Given the code (automatic conversion to function pointer of appropriate type):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#if 0

template< typename L, typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto 
to_function_pointer(L l, R (L::*)(A...) const)
{
    return static_cast< R (*)(A...) >(l);
}

template< typename L, typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto 
to_function_pointer(L l, R (L::*)(A...))
{
    return static_cast< R (*)(A...) >(l);
}

template< typename L >
constexpr
auto 
to_function_pointer(L l)
{
    return to_function_pointer(l, &L::operator ());
}

#endif

template< typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto
to_function_pointer(R (* fp)(A...))
{
    return fp;
}

namespace
{

void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

}

int main()
{
    to_function_pointer(f)();
    to_function_pointer(&f)();
    to_function_pointer([] () { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; })();
    to_function_pointer([] () mutable { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; })();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For `#if 0` function `to_function_pointer` from the code can't convert a lambda to the corresponding function pointer. Does it mean that mentioned operator is "implicitly" marked by the `explicit` keyword? Is there a corresponding clause from the standard?

Comment: Is [this](http://rextester.com/DTUR53479) what you are looking for? I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I looking exactly for answers to my questions marked by "?" signs. A copying of [my workable code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/662f4fca9f3ac5ef) is not the solution IAC.

Comment: What do you mean by `For #if 0 it can't convert...` The code between `#if 0` and `#endif` is skipped by the compiler - who do you mean by "it", then? What code are you actually compiling, and what errors are you seeing? When you say `Does it mean that it is "implicitly" marked by the explicit keyword?` - does *what* mean that, and *what* is so marked? You use "it" a lot, but it's unclear (to me, at least) what each occurrence of the pronoun stands for.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "It" is placeholder for latest introduced  noun (usually from previous sentence).

Comment: So your questions should be read this way, then: "For `#if 0` type can't convert a lambda to the corresponding function pointer. Does pointer mean that pointer is "implicitly" marked by the explicit keyword?" I'm afraid these sentences don't make much sense to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please, never mind. If you want I can delete the question entirely. Do you want?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Another possibility for you is to correct my question in a way you want and I can accept your changes.

Comment: If you no longer want help with a problem, then by all means, go ahead and delete the question. If you do still want help with a problem, then I suggest you explain that problem more clearly. At the very least, post the actual code that fails to compile, and error messages you see when trying to compile it. I cannot correct your question as I do not understand the nature of the problem you want help with; if I did, I wouldn't need to ask for clarifications.